# Testing tool For .Net Window based applications

Tags: .net

I am working in .NET Window based application.

I want to test my application using  automation testing.

Are there any tools for it?

Answer (score 2):

Try NUnit (http://www.nunit.org/). It's a most popular testing framawork in .net

Answer (score 0):

- NUnit for unit testing
- SpecFlow for end to end, BDD style testing
- I would also use NSubstitute for mocking; NBuilder for data generation

Answer (score 0):

You can try [White](http://teststack.github.io/White/):

> White is a framework for automating rich client applications based on
>   Win32, WinForms, WPF, Silverlight and SWT (Java) platforms. It is .NET
>   based and does not require the use of any proprietary scripting
>   languages. Tests/automation programs using White can be written with
>   whatever .NET language, IDE and tools you are already using. White
>   provides a consistent object-oriented API, hiding the complexity of
>   Microsoft's UIAutomation library (on which White is based) and windows
>   messages.

And I see people using White along with [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org/specflownew/):

> SpecFlow aims at bridging the communication gap between domain experts
>   and developers by binding business readable behavior specifications
>   and examples to the underlying implementation.
>
> Our mission is to provide a pragmatic and frictionless approach to
>   Specification-By-Example for .NET projects.
>
> SpecFlow also supports the concepts of Acceptance Test Driven
>   Development (ATDD) and Behavior Driven Development (BDD), which are
>   often used synonymously with Specification-By-Example.
>
> SpecFlow is open source and provided under a BSD license. As a part of
>   the Cucumber family, SpecFlow uses the official Gherkin parser and
>   provides integration to the .NET framework, Silverlight, Windows Phone
>   and Mono.

An article about using SpecFlow with White is [here](http://devblog.cloudreach.co.uk/2012/05/behaviour-driven-development-in-net.html).